# jasvascript call functions from different scripts

Tags: javascript, onclick, function-call

I have two different script tags,can i call function from second..like this

```
<script>
var = something;
. . .
<td onclick="myFunc("+something+")"></td>
</script> 

<script>
  function myFunc(data){..}
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. `<td onclick="myFunc("+something+")"></td>` is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<td>` tag out of `<script>` tag down after second `<script>` and you will be able to.

Btw, consider changing blockquotes in `<td onclick="myFunc("+something+")"></td>` to quotes like this `<td onclick="myFunc('+something+')"></td>`, other way your HTML will not be parsed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The functions are at the global level. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hi() {
      alert('hi');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
hi();
</script>
```

This does indeed result in a popup with "hi".

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/we8pb7md/

Comment: but can i use variables in those functions? variables declared in first,used in second?

Comment: @miskomiskovic No, not unless you make them globals by omitting the `var` -- if you make them globals, they'll work. But it is bad practice -- it is good idea to use CommonJS or some other module system but it requires tooling/time/setup.